# IE :When a large table is printed, it is truncated to the first page

Tags: html, internet-explorer, printing

I have the following code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >

        <HTML>
           <HEAD>
           <meta http-equiv='x-ua-compatible' content='IE=8'>
        </HEAD>
        <Tbody>
        <tr Rowspan="1">
        <td>
    content1..
    <br/>
    content2..
    <br/>
    ....
    ....
    ...
    content1000..
    <br/>

        </tr>
<!-- 2nd row starts here -->
        <tr Rowspan="1">
        <td>
    content1001..
    <br/>
    content1002..
    <br/>
    ....
    ....
    ...
    content10000..
    <br/>

        </tr>

        </tbody>
        </html>
```

If I print preview this in Windows 7, IE8 or IE 9, the preview shows only first page
that is, content1,2...say 50 is shown
the rest of the contents until content1000 are not shown
the display is limited to 1 page only

Is there a problem in my HTML?

This is a dynamic HTML content and varies case to case basis.

Edit:
I tried removing the `<meta http-equiv='x-ua-compatible' content='IE=8'>`
and the full contents were shown in the print preview.

However page break is not working in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve.... a table i think but you were missing a few things:

- body tags
- table tags
- closing /td tags

It should look something like this:

```
<body>
<table>
 <tr Rowspan="1">
    <td>
        content1..<br/>
        content2..<br/>
        content1000..<br/>
     </td>
 </tr>
<tr Rowspan="1">
    <td>
        content1001..<br/>
        content1002..<br/>
        content10000..<br/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Also, the `<br />` is a line break which breaks a sentence, not a page